# Any way to obtain a Java class from a Scala (2.10) type tag or symbol?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Looks like this gets me close, but (a) not quite (see below), and (b) using the string representation of a name feels like a hack...

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val t = typeOf[Int]
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Int

scala> t.typeSymbol.asClass.fullName
res0: String = scala.Int

scala> object X { class Y } 
defined module X

scala> val y = typeOf[X.Y]
y: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = X.Y

scala> Class.forName(y.typeSymbol.asClass.fullName)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: X.Y [...]
```

Am I missing some more direct method of accessing this information?  Or is it going to be best, if I also need the class information at some point, just to keep a parallel set of Java class info?  (Ugh!)

Comment: if your can get an instance of an AnyRef type, can't you just revert to java.lang.Object-y goodness, and call myObj.getClass().getName()?

Comment: for example, object X { class Y }
defined module X

scala> (new X.Y).getClass.getName
res7: java.lang.String = X$Y

Comment: As a quick suggestion, try running `scala -Xprint:typer` to see if and how the REPL is actually wrapping the X into it's own objects.

Comment: I've been trying and failing to get `Class.forName(package.and.object)` to work in the REPL.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Receiving a `java.lang.Class` or instantiating objects with reflection must be done with a mirror and not with types and symbols, which are compile time information for Scala:

```
scala> val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
m: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with ...

scala> m.runtimeClass(typeOf[X.Y].typeSymbol.asClass)
res25: Class[_] = class X$Y
```

Comment: He only says "class information", no mention of instantiation. But still, this maybe his use case...

Comment: That appears to do it, as long as you happen to choose the correct class loader.

Comment: The `ClassMirror.runtimeClass` functionality has been removed from RC1, because there's a shorter alternative: just `m.runtimeClass(typeOf[X.Y].typeSymbol.asClass)`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `tag` is the type tag of the class you want to get the java class for, you can say:

```
val mirror = tag.mirror
val clazz = mirror.runtimeClass(tag.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass)
```

Basically the same as sschaef's answer, except you should use the mirror directly from the tag, instead of using the mirror of the current class' classloader.  If the current class and the other class which you have the tag for use diferent classloaders, you would have a classloading error in that case, but no error in the way I explained.

The `clazz` variable will hold the java class for whatever you're trying to get.