# Obtain Java Class from Scala TypeTag in Macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect

According to this question/answer [Any way to obtain a Java class from a Scala (2.10) type tag or symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901823/any-way-to-obtain-a-java-class-from-a-scala-2-10-type-tag-or-symbol)
I should use `runtimeClass` to obtain the `Class` from a type.

But if I do reflection in Macros I don't have access to `runtimeClass`. 
How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In macros, you can have a `TypeTag` for a class which isn't actually compiled yet and thus doesn't have a `Class` object, that's *why* there is no `runtimeClass`. If you want to try anyway (e.g. because you know the class is from a dependency, not being compiled), I don't know any way other than `Class.forName`, as in the question. Of course, you can use `runtimeClass` in the *generated* code.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can use runtime reflection in macros (for classes existing during macro expansion i.e. during compilation of main code)

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def printJavaClass[T]: Unit = macro printJavaClassImpl[T]

def printJavaClassImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val clazz = rm.runtimeClass(weakTypeOf[T].asInstanceOf[rm.universe.Type])
  println(clazz)

  q"()"
}
```

```scala
printJavaClass[String] // scalac: class java.lang.String
```

[Type class instance for case objects defined in sealed trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990571/type-class-instance-for-case-objects-defined-in-sealed-trait)

[How to accept only a specific subtype of existential type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916325/how-to-accept-only-a-specific-subtype-of-existential-type)

[In a scala macro, how to get the full name that a class will have at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64472135/in-a-scala-macro-how-to-get-the-full-name-that-a-class-will-have-at-runtime)

---

Sometimes you can also cast compiler mirror to runtime mirror

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {
  def printJavaClass[T]: Unit = macro printJavaClassImpl[T]

  def printJavaClassImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val rm = c.mirror.asInstanceOf[c.universe.RuntimeMirror]
    val clazz = rm.runtimeClass(weakTypeOf[T].asInstanceOf[rm.universe.Type])
    //val clazz = rm.runtimeClass(weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.asInstanceOf[rm.universe.ClassSymbol])
    //val clazz = rm.runtimeClass(weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass)
    println(clazz)

    q"()"
  }
}
```

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val rm = runtime.currentMirror
val tb = rm.mkToolBox()
tb.eval(q"Macros.printJavaClass[String]") // at runtime: class java.lang.String
```

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12680

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/RINjJfNsRNqprn9nR1ZpDQ/14

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/RINjJfNsRNqprn9nR1ZpDQ/26

but not always

```scala
Macros.printJavaClass[String] // doesn't compile
// exception during macro expansion: 
// java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalMirror cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Mirrors$RuntimeMirror
```