# Type class instance for case objects defined in sealed trait

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, typeclass, implicit

In Scala 2.13 I have a case where I define some operation for all of types extending some sealed trait `EnumType`. I made it working but I'd like `getTypeClass` function not to be dependant on concrete types extending `EnumType`. Now I have to visit this function any time `EnumType` changes and add or remove some pattern. Is there a way to get instances of `Operation` type class for `EnumType` types but without pattern matching on all of them?

```scala
  sealed trait EnumType
  case object Add10 extends EnumType
  case object Add50 extends EnumType

  trait Operation[+T] {
    def op(a: Int): Int
  }

  implicit val add10: Operation[Add10.type] = (a: Int) => a + 10
  implicit val add50: Operation[Add50.type] = (a: Int) => a + 50

  def getTypeClass(enumType: EnumType): Operation[EnumType] = {
    // I need to modify this pattern matching
    // every time EnumType changes
    enumType match {
      case Add10 => implicitly[Operation[Add10.type]]
      case Add50 => implicitly[Operation[Add50.type]]
    }

    // I'd wish it could be done with without pattern matching like (it does not compile):
    //   implicitly[Operation[concrete_type_of(enumType)]]
  }

  // value of enumType is dynamic - it can be even decoded from some json document
  val enumType: EnumType = Add50
  println(getTypeClass(enumType).op(10)) // prints 60
```

EDIT
That's the way I wish it was called without using explicit subtypes of `EnumType` (using `circe` in this example to decode json) :

```scala
  case class Doc(enumType: EnumType, param: Int)

  implicit val docDecoder: Decoder[Doc] = deriveDecoder
  implicit val enumTypeDecoder: Decoder[EnumType] = deriveEnumerationDecoder

  decode[Doc]("""{"enumType": "Add10", "param": 10}""").map {
    doc =>
      println(getTypeClass(doc.enumType).call(doc.param))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only know that statically `enumType` has type just `EnumType` and want to match based on runtime value/runtime class of `enumType`, you'll have to use some kind of reflection:

- either runtime compilation with [reflective toolbox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes) (resolving implicits at runtime)

```scala
// libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
  
def getTypeClass(enumType: EnumType): Operation[EnumType] =
  tb.eval(q"_root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Operation[${cm.moduleSymbol(enumType.getClass)}]]")
    .asInstanceOf[Operation[EnumType]]
```

or

```scala
def getTypeClass(enumType: EnumType): Operation[EnumType] =
  tb.eval(tb.untypecheck(tb.inferImplicitValue(
    appliedType(
      typeOf[Operation[_]].typeConstructor,
      cm.moduleSymbol(enumType.getClass).moduleClass.asClass.toType
    ),
    silent = false
  ))).asInstanceOf[Operation[EnumType]]
```

or

```scala
def getTypeClass(enumType: EnumType): Operation[EnumType] = {
  val cases = typeOf[EnumType].typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.map(subclass => {
    val module = subclass.asClass.module
    val pattern = pq"`$module`"
    cq"$pattern => _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Operation[$module.type]]"
  })
  tb.eval(q"(et: EnumType) => et match { case ..$cases }")
    .asInstanceOf[EnumType => Operation[EnumType]]
    .apply(enumType)
}
```

- or a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) (automating the pattern matching)

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def getTypeClass(enumType: EnumType): Operation[EnumType] = macro getTypeClassImpl

def getTypeClassImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(enumType: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val cases = typeOf[EnumType].typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.map(subclass => {
    val module = subclass.asClass.module
    val pattern = pq"`$module`"
    cq"$pattern => _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Operation[$module.type]]"
  })
  q"$enumType match { case ..$cases }"
}

//scalac: App.this.enumType match {
//  case Add10 => _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Macro.Operation[Add10.type]]
//  case Add50 => _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Macro.Operation[Add50.type]]
//}
```

Since all the objects are defined at compile time I guess that a macro is better.

[Covariant case class mapping to its base class without a type parameter and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556749/covariant-case-class-mapping-to-its-base-class-without-a-type-parameter-and-back)

[Getting subclasses of a sealed trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534002/getting-subclasses-of-a-sealed-trait)

[Iteration over a sealed trait in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala)

You can even make a macro [whitebox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html#blackbox-and-whitebox-macros), then using [runtime reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) in the macro you can have `Add50` type statically (if the class is known during macro expansion)

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

def getTypeClass(enumType: EnumType): Operation[EnumType] = macro getTypeClassImpl

def getTypeClassImpl(c: whitebox.Context)(enumType: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val clazz = c.eval(c.Expr[EnumType](c.untypecheck(enumType))).getClass
  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val symbol = rm.moduleSymbol(clazz)
  //q"_root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Operation[${symbol.asInstanceOf[ModuleSymbol]}.type]]" // implicit not found
  //q"_root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Operation[${symbol/*.asInstanceOf[ModuleSymbol]*/.moduleClass.asClass.toType.asInstanceOf[Type]}]]" // implicit not found
    // "migrating" symbol from runtime universe to macro universe
  c.parse(s"_root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Operation[${symbol.fullName}.type]]")
}
```

```scala
object App {
  val enumType: EnumType = Add50
}
```

```scala
val operation = getTypeClass(App.enumType)
operation: Operation[Add50.type] // not just Operation[EnumType]
operation.op(10) // 60
```

[How to accept only a specific subtype of existential type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916325/how-to-accept-only-a-specific-subtype-of-existential-type)

[In a scala macro, how to get the full name that a class will have at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64472135/in-a-scala-macro-how-to-get-the-full-name-that-a-class-will-have-at-runtime)

Comment: Thank you Dmytro for the solution and all additional resources. I'll go with macro version as you suggest - it works as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def getTypeClass[T <: EnumType : Operation](t: T) = implicitly[Operation[T]]

 println(getTypeClass(Add50).op(10))
```

In fact, you don't even need `getTypeClass` at all:

```
def operate[T <: EnumType : Operation](t: T)(param: Int) = implicitly[Operation[T]].op(param)

println(operate(Add50)(10))
```

The `Foo : Bar` notation I used above is equivalent to this:

```
def operate[T <: EnumType](t: T)(param: Int)(op: Operation[T]) = op.op(param)
```

Note, that you are not actually *using* instances of `Add50` and `Add10` anywhere. They could just be traits rather than objects (IMO, that better reflects the intent):

```
  sealed trait EnumType
  trait Add10 extends EnumType
  trait Add50 extends EnumType

  trait Operation[+T] {
    def op(a: Int): Int
  }

  implicit val add10: Operation[Add10] = (a: Int) => a + 10
  implicit val add50: Operation[Add50] = (a: Int) => a + 50

  def operate[T <: EnumType : Operation](param: Int) = 
   implicitly[Operation[T]].op(param)

 println(operate[Add50](10))
```

Comment: I'm afraid your solution will not work in OP's settings. Can you see that OP writes: *"value of enumType is dynamic - it can be even decoded from some json document `val enumType: EnumType = Add50`"*? So the static type of `enumType` is just `EnumType`. Your solution will give "implicit not found" or "ambiguous implicits".

Comment: Dima, thank you for your answer. You were able to remove pattern matching because you changed the way how you call the function. You call it by providing explicit `Add50` type, however in my case I will have some `EnumType` which will be known only at runtime and that's why I included casting here:
`val enumType: EnumType = Add50`

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, if you don't know the type at compile time, then you are stuck with pattern matching. Either that, or just add add `getOperation` to `EnumType` itself. But FWIW, I don't think you actually _need_ it: from the code perspective, there isn't much difference between `foo(Add50)` and `foo[Add50]`, except that the latter lets you do what you want and the former does not.

Comment: @Dima Both`foo(Add50)` and `foo[Add50]` would be ok but OP doesn't have either of them, just `foo(enumType)` for `enumType: EnumType`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin yes, but where does `enumType` come from? You either  set it right there like `val enumType = Add50` or it comes as a parameter `def foo(enumType: ЕnumType)`. So, the point is that the first case is trivial, and the second can easily be changed to `def foo[T <: EnumType: Operation]`

Comment: @Dima *"yes, but where does `enumType` come from?"* If I understood OP correctly, he is parsing a string (json). *"the second can easily be changed to `def foo[T: EnumType]`"* I guess you meant `T <: EnumType`. Not easily if we don't have `T` statically.