# How to change base class field in functional fashion in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, polymorphism, typeclass, implicit

Say I have this hierarchy

```
trait Base {
  val tag: String
}

case class Derived1(tag: String = "Derived 1") extends Base
case class Derived2(tag: String = "Derived 2") extends Base
//etc ...
```

and I want to define method with following signature

```
def tag[T <: Base](instance: T, tag: String): T
```

that returns an instance of type `T` with modified `tag: String`. So when e.g. a `Derived1` instance is passed in a modified instance of the same type is returned.

This goal could be easily accomplished by using mutable `tag` variable `var tag: String`. How to achieve desired behaviour using scala and functional programming?

My thought:

I could create a type class and its instances

```
trait Tagger[T] {
  def tag(t: T, state: String): T
}

implicit object TaggerDerived1 extends Tagger[Derived1] {
  override def tag(t: Derived1, state: String): Derived1 = ???
}

implicit object TaggerDerived2 extends Tagger[Derived2] {
  override def tag(t: Derived2, state: String): Derived2 = ???
}

implicit object TaggerBase extends Tagger[Base] {
  override def tag(t: Base, state: String): Base = ???
}
```

and a method

```
def tag[T <: Base](instance: T, tag: String)(implicit tagger: Tagger[T]): T = tagger.tag(instance, tag)
```

This is not ideal, because first of all user must be aware of this when defining their own derived classes. When not defining one, the implicit resolution would fall back to base implementation and narrow the returning type.

```
case class Derived3(tag: String = "Derived 3") extends Base


tag(Derived3(), "test") // falls back to `tag[Base](...)`
```

Now I am leaning towards using mutable state by employing `var tag: String`. However, I would love to hear some opinions how to resolve this purely functionally in scala.

Comment: You found this FAQ: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type and as you can read, a typeclass like yours is really the only safe option, other methods like F-Bounded may reduce some boilerplate but the essential problem is the same, there is no way to abstract over constructors. - Another approach is to prefer composition over inheritance and move `tag` to another class like `TaggedBase[B <: Base](b: B, tag: String)`

Comment: Why not `instance.copy(tag = "new value")`?

Comment: @GaëlJ you can't know `instance` will have `copy`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you for your comment. I was also thinking about F-bounded polymorphism, but I believe that it doesn't work with multiple level hierarchies. I guess I will go with the var.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Case classes normally have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *derive* your type class `Tagger` and then the users will not have to define its instances for every new case class extending `Base`

```scala
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
import shapeless.labelled.{FieldType, field}
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil, LabelledGeneric, Witness}

trait Tagger[T] {
  def tag(t: T, state: String): T
}

trait LowPriorityTagger {
  implicit def notTagFieldTagger[K <: Symbol : Witness.Aux, V, T <: HList](implicit
    tagger: Tagger[T]
  ): Tagger[FieldType[K, V] :: T] =
    (t, state) => t.head :: tagger.tag(t.tail, state)
}

object Tagger extends LowPriorityTagger {
  implicit def genericTagger[T <: Base with Product, L <: HList](implicit
    generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, L],
    tagger: Tagger[L]
  ): Tagger[T] = (t, state) => generic.from(tagger.tag(generic.to(t), state))

  implicit val hnilTagger: Tagger[HNil] = (_, _) => HNil

  implicit def tagFieldTagger[T <: HList]:
    Tagger[FieldType[Witness.`'tag`.T, String] :: T] = 
    (t, state) => field[Witness.`'tag`.T](state) :: t.tail
}
```

```scala
case class Derived1(tag: String = "Derived 1") extends Base
case class Derived2(tag: String = "Derived 2") extends Base
case class Derived3(i: Int, tag: String = "Derived 3", s: String) extends Base

tag(Derived1("aaa"), "bbb") // Derived1(bbb)
tag(Derived2("ccc"), "ddd") // Derived2(ddd)
tag(Derived3(1, "ccc", "xxx"), "ddd") // Derived3(1,ddd,xxx)
```

Alternatively for single-parameter case classes you can constrain `T` so that it has `.copy`

```scala
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
def tag[T <: Base {def copy(tag: String): T}](instance: T, tag: String): T =
  instance.copy(tag = tag)
```

For multi-parameter case classes it's harder to express in types the existence of `.copy` because the method signature becomes unknown (to be calculated).

So you can make `tag` a macro

```scala
// libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def tag[T <: Base](instance: T, tag: String): T = macro tagImpl

def tagImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(instance: c.Tree, tag: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"$instance.copy(tag = $tag)"
}
```

Or you can use runtime reflection (Java or Scala, using `Product` functionality or not)

```scala
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => rm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TermName, termNames}

def tag[T <: Base with Product : ClassTag](instance: T, tag: String): T = {
    // Product
  val values = instance.productElementNames.zip(instance.productIterator)
    .map {case fieldName -> fieldValue => if (fieldName == "tag") tag else fieldValue}.toSeq

    // Java reflection
  // val clazz = instance.getClass
  // clazz.getMethods.find(_.getName == "copy").get.invoke(instance, values: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  // clazz.getConstructors.head.newInstance(values: _*).asInstanceOf[T]

    // Scala reflection
  val clazz = classTag[T].runtimeClass
  val classSymbol = rm.classSymbol(clazz)
  // val copyMethodSymbol = classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(TermName("copy")).asMethod
  // rm.reflect(instance).reflectMethod(copyMethodSymbol)(values: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  val constructorSymbol = classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  rm.reflectClass(classSymbol).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)(values: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for investing your time in the answer, it was very helpful to me.  I have never come across the shapeless library. I have been studying it the all day long today. Just if you didn't mind to shed some light on a few things that are not 100% clear to me. 1) Why the generic parameter `T` in `genericTagger` must extend `Product` ?  2) Why the generic parameter `K` in `notTagFieldTagger` is context bounded to `Witness.Aux`? Is it in order to be as specific as possible, so it doesn't match potential different case?

Comment: @DavidTomecek Yeah, you can remove all upper/context bounds except `T <: HList` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/JpkFgEDLTUmD7x18V92hOA Just case classes extend `Product` and keys in records are `Symbol` singleton types (not `<: Singleton` or `: ValueOf` for technical reasons but `: Witness.Aux`).

Comment: @DavidTomecek You would need `<: Product` only if you used `.productElementNames`, `.productIterator` etc. And you would need `: Witness.Aux` only if you materialized the keys i.e. transformed them from types into values.

Comment: @DavidTomecek In the question you wrote that you need for some reason not only `Tagger[Derived1]`, `Tagger[Derived2]` ... but also `Tagger[Base]`. You can automate its defining (with pattern matching, I guess) as well like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990571/type-class-instance-for-case-objects-defined-in-sealed-trait (just objects should be replaced with case classes).