# Scala upper type bounds for reflectioned type

Tags: scala, reflection

For instance a have a type `B`. I know it is subtype of `A`.
I want to use type `B` in runtime, having only class name and using reflection.

I am trying to get it with `Class.forName("B").asSubclass(classOf[A])`

The problem is, I cant use this type in upper bounded functions
`def test[T <: A]() = ???`

Minimal example:

```
trait A
class B extends A

val cls: Class[_ <: A] = Class.forName("B").asSubclass(classOf[A])

def test[T <: A]() = ???

test[cls.type]()   // Error: type arguments cls.type 
                   // do not conform to upper bound A 
                   // of type parameter T
```

Any way to make compiler work?

Comment: `cls.type` is `Class[_ <: A]`. You want to pass `_ <: A` into `test[...]` without this `Class[...]` part.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok It it possible?

Comment: Overloading `def type[T <: A](@unused clazz: Class[T]) = type[T]()` and then `test(cls)` should work.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok can you provide minimal example as an answer pls? Its not clear for me, how to use `def type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. Currently this sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Here seems to be a confusion of *type* (normally existing at compile time) and *class* (normally existing at runtime)

[What is the difference between a class and a type in Scala (and Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031640/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-type-in-scala-and-java)

[What is the difference between Type and Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468145/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class)

https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

`test[cls.type]` doesn't make sense. `x.type` is a singleton type.

Maybe what @MateuszKubuszok proposed can help

```scala
trait A
class B extends A
class C

def test[T <: A](): Unit = ??? 

def test[T <: A](@unused clazz: Class[T]): Unit = test[T]()

val cls: Class[_ <: A] = Class.forName("B").asSubclass(classOf[A])
val cls1: Class[_] = classOf[C]

test(cls) // compiles
test(cls1) // doesn't compile, inferred type arguments [_$2] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: A], type mismatch: found: Class[_$2] where type _$2, required: Class[T]
```

If you really want to substitute a class into a type-parameter position of a generic method then the problem is that `T` being a subtype of `A` or not, should be checked by the compiler at compile time while `Class[_]` object exists at runtime. So if you really want this you should find a way either to have the class earlier, at compile time, e.g. with a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) (using runtime reflection in macros: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380944/obtain-java-class-from-scala-typetag-in-macros) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990571/type-class-instance-for-case-objects-defined-in-sealed-trait) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916325/how-to-accept-only-a-specific-subtype-of-existential-type) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64472135/in-a-scala-macro-how-to-get-the-full-name-that-a-class-will-have-at-runtime))

```scala
trait A
class B extends A
class C

val cls: Class[_ <: A] = Class.forName("B").asSubclass(classOf[A])
val cls1: Class[_] = classOf[C]

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox // libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => rm, universe => ru}

def checkB(): Unit = macro Macros.checkBImpl
def checkC(): Unit = macro Macros.checkCImpl

class Macros(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  val cm = c.mirror

  // weird :)
  def register(name: String): Unit =
    rm.runtimeClass(cm.staticClass(name).asInstanceOf[ru.ClassSymbol])

  def checkBImpl(): Tree = impl(cls)
  def checkCImpl(): Tree = impl(cls1)

  def impl(cls: Class[_]): Tree = {
    register(cls.getName) // side effect (otherwise even for B: type arguments [B] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: A])
    q"App.test[${rm.classSymbol(cls).toType.asInstanceOf[Type]}]()"
  }
}
```

```scala
// in a different subproject

object App {
  def test[T <: A]() = ???
}

checkB() // compiles
checkC() // doesn't compile: type arguments [C] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: A]
```

or vice versa, to postpone type checking till runtime, e.g. with runtime compilation (using reflective [toolbox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes))

```scala
trait A
class B extends A
class C

object App {
  def test[T <: A]() = ???
}

val cls: Class[_ <: A] = Class.forName("B").asSubclass(classOf[A])
val cls1 = classOf[C]

import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => rm, universe => ru}
import ru.Quasiquote
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox // libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
val tb = rm.mkToolBox()

def check(cls: Class[_]): Unit = tb.typecheck(q"App.test[${rm.classSymbol(cls)}]()")

check(cls) // at runtime: ok
check(cls1) // at runtime: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective typecheck has failed: type arguments [C] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: A]
```

Besides `tb.typecheck` there are also `tb.compile`, `tb.eval`.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. The meta problem is I want to parse and read protos from a big backup using `scalaPB`. It requires to summon `GeneratedMessageCompanion[A <: GeneratedMessage]` instance and invoke `parseFrom` method for specific contract.

Comment: @Oleg Interesting. It's not clear for me though whether you actually need both `Class[_]` objects and generic methods (with `A <: ...`). Maybe you can avoid `Class[_]`. Maybe you'll have more conventional Scala then (using just macros or just runtime-reflection but not mixing macros with runtime reflection or runtime reflection with runtime compilation). If you still have questions maybe you could create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your ScalaPB setting (in this question or maybe better in  a new one) and we'll see.

Comment: @Oleg Do MateuszKubuszok's approach or one of mine work for you?